# how to show that a nonsingular positive semidefinite matrix is positive definite?

Tags: positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

Got a question regarding the following statement: a nonsingular positive semidefinite matrix is positive definite. Is this true? If yes, how to show it.

If the above statement is not true, how about this statement: a symmetric nonsingular positive semidefinite matrix is positive definite. Is this true? If yes, how to show it.

Thanks!

Comment: For symmetric matrices, positive definite = all eigenvalues positive, positive semidefinite = all eigenvalues nonnegative. Nonsingular = all eigenvalues nonzero.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks, this is very helpful! So it seems that we do need the symmetry restriction (for nonsingularity to imply positive definiteness), right?

Comment: I have only ever looked at the notions of positive definiteness and positive semidefiniteness in the context of symmetric matrices. For matrices that are not symmetric, the connection to eigenvalues is lost. See, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_matrix#Extension_for_non-Hermitian_square_matrices

Comment: for part 1, consider matrices like $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 &0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 1 &0\end{bmatrix}  $